# Formatting numbers to n decimal places without rounding

Tags: c++

I want to create a c++ program to calculate the average of 3 positive numbers

where (x,y,z)>0 and (x,y,z)<=10

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    cin >> x >> y >> z;
    double x1,y1,z1,ma;
    x1 = x;
    y1 = y;
    z1 = z;

    if(x>0 && x<=10 && y>0 && y<=10 && z>0 && z<=10)
        ma = (x1+y1+z1)/3;
    else
        return 0;

    printf("%.2f" , ma);

    return 0;
}
```

For x=9, y=9 and z=5 the average is 23/3=7.666666666666667 and when I format to 2 decimal places, the result will be 7.67, but I want to appear 7.66 not 7.67.

Please, can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Without using other functions, you could do:

```
double x = (double)((int)(23 * 100 / 3)) / 100.0;
```

Or even a bit simpler:

```
double x = (double)(int)(23 * 100 / 3) / 100.0;
```

The `int` cast truncates the remaining digits (so there is no rounding).

In C++11 there is also the [trunc()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc) function to do just that.